# Android: Updating to latest version of SDK

Tags: android, sdk

On Google's website it states:

"If you're already using the Android SDK, you should update to the latest tools or platform using the Android SDK and AVD Manager"

The current version is 18 but when I run the SDK and AVD Manager, it never shows either version 17 or 18  as an available update. Any reason for this? I hate the thought of having to install the latest version from scratch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible reasons for SDK Manager:

- Unchecked Updates/New
- Problems with connection, check Preferences in SDK Manager

BTW: current Android SDK Tools revision is 19

Answer (score 0):

if you use windows, check that you user eclipse as administrator, that was my fault on updateing.